# What library can I use to display 3D images and/or point clouds in my GUI?

Tags: c++, qt, point-clouds, point-cloud-library

I am currently writing a GUI in Qt (C++), and I've been on the lookout for something that will just let me open PCD images (point cloud), along with the ability to drag the image around.

I've looked through Blender, and MeshLab APIs (the latter defied my understanding), and lately PCLVisualizer to no luck.

Any input on the simplest way to go about this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are writing your GUI in Qt, you might want to use a Qt widget developed to display 3D point clouds to use with the PCL library. It was written by Walter Lucetti and was available on his company website [Rekno.it](http://www.rekno.it/page.php?page=Code).

Unfortunately, the code is no longer available there. A quick web search pointed me to this [github repository](http://code.google.com/p/miminect), which still holds a copy of the widget code. The relevant class is `CPCLOpenglWidget`. You can also find a complete example of PCL+QT+Kinect integration for real time point clouds visualization.

Comment: Thought this helped the most, even though the other answer is very valid.

Comment: For displaying a `pcl::PointCloud` in Qt, have a look a [this](http://www.pcl-users.org/QT-PCLVisualizer-mostly-working-td3285187.html), it uses the `QVTKWidget` and the `vtkRendererWindow` to integrate the `PCLVisualizer` into Qt.

Answer (score 2):

The cloud viewer:

http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/cloud_viewer.php#cloud-viewer

Will allow you to have this visualisation. If you want to view pcd files you will need to decode it and create a point cloud to use this visualisation but it should be easy enough to edit.

You can use this link:

http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/reading_pcd.php#reading-pcd

Which will teach to read PCD files and create a point cloud.

Combining these should allow you to easily visualise PCD files.